# Python3 - How does using `super` inside a method being overridden works (more in body)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, super

There is class structure like shown below:

```
class RegressionResults(LikelihoodModelResults):
    ...
    ...
    def conf_int(self, alpha=.05, cols=None):
        ci = super(RegressionResults, self).conf_int(alpha=alpha, cols=cols)
        return ci
```

and here is `LikelihoodModelResults`:

```
class LikelihoodModelResults(Results):
    ...
    ...
    def conf_int(self, alpha=.05, cols=None):
    ...
    ...
```

and the class `Results` doesn't have a method called `conf_int`.

Given such structure of classes and inheritence, I would like to know what happens when `conf_int` is called on the instance of `RegressionResults`. will the code inside `conf_int` of `LikelihoodModelResults` be run? if yes, why even try to override it?

I am sorry, if i have been vague in the question's title, you are free to edit it if you have a better title. And sources of above classes are [`RegressionResults`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py#L1568), [`LikelihoodModelResults`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/base/model.py#L1198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of code the overridden method does nothing extra, so you're right that the override seems redundant. However, in the original source it has a large docstring and then this comment inside the method body:

```
# keep method for docstring for now
```

So I assume the override is there for documentation purposes rather than mechanical ones.

Comment: thanks @Kemp, got it. so, this `super` lets the `conf_int`'s code from `LikelihoodModelResults` be run, but the method is being overridden only to replace the docstring.